# r: get columns that only have NaN value

Tags: r, nan, na

sample code:

`df`:

```
#                        a                       b                       c
# 1 -0.0010616345688829504  -4.1135727372109387e-05 -0.0001814242939304348
```

There is only 1 row and 3000+ columns.

I was wondering how I can select only the columns with `NaN`  (of which there is as I have confirmed looking at the data.) Would also be great if with `NA` as well if the code is significantly different.

I tried using `is.nan` but it didnt go so well. I was previously using `df,which(df[1,]== some value)]` for other values like numerics and logicals but doesnt work with NaN and NA.

Expecting something like this:

`res`:

```
#   d                                              
# 1 NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a very simple solution pass a logical vector in base R

```
df[, is.na(df)]
```

This returns columns with NA and NaN

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) is.nan(x), df)
#   d
#1 NaN
```

---

It may be better to do `unlist` as there is only a single row

```
df[is.nan(unlist(df))]
```

`is.nan` would give `FALSE` for `NA` while `is.na` gives `TRUE` for both

```
is.nan(c(NA, NaN))
#[1] FALSE  TRUE
is.na(c(NA, NaN))
#[1] TRUE TRUE
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a = -0.0010616345688829504, 
    b = -4.1135727372109387e-05, c =  -0.0001814242939304348, d = NaN)
```